# algebraic attacks for mixed operations (mod 2 and mod 256)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, xor, algebraic-attack

If a cipher has mixed operations, e.g $\oplus$ (addition mod $2$), and addition modulo $2^8$. How we we going to express them mathematically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both bitwise exclusive-or and addition can easily be expressed mathematically.  What are you asking?

Comment: is there any way of expressing exclusive or as addition modulo $2^8$ or vice versa?

Comment: Anything wrong with the trivial: if $\oplus$ is addition modulo $2$ and $\widetilde+$ is addition modulo $2^8$, then for all integers $a$ and $b$, $a\oplus b=((a\widetilde+b)\bmod 2)$? Or perhaps you have a definition of $\oplus$ which is [_bitwise_ XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), _not_ "addition mod $2$" as stated in the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is of course but because of carry bits there will be data-dependent "nonlinear" terms. If I do it for 2 bits you can get the idea. It gets unwieldy but you can easily write code to do it for longer bitlengths. The list below is an XOR table expressed as integers:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\oplus & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & \color{red}0 & 3 & \color{red}2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & \color{red}2 & 1 & \color{red}0 \\
\end{array}
$$

while the table below is addition mod 4:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & \color{green}2 & 3 & \color{green}0 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & \color{green}0 & 1 & \color{green}2 \\
\end{array}
$$

Note that there are exactly 4 positions (in general for $n$ bits there will be $2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\cdots$ such positions) where the two operations differ, so relatively worse as $n$ increases) where the two differ. Can we express these positions in terms of integer properties?

The answer is: Let $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_4,$ considered as an additive group. Then  the XOR operation on $x,y$ can be defined as

$$
x \oplus y = \begin{cases}
x + y + 2 ~(\text{mod } 4) &
\text{if }   x \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod } 2)
\text{ and } y \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod } 2) \\
x + y ~(\text{mod } 4) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

The full answer has to do with the highest powers of $2$ dividing the two numbers within $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n},$ i.e., the subring and ideal structure.

Comment: The "in general part" is not correct, the sum is $2^n-1 = 4$. there is no solution.